# How to compose validation functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I've been asked to compose the functions that validate data of a form that has inputs for title and description

In the code below I'm making validations using `if`s but my teacher asked me to convert those `if`s in functions and compose them.

```
validate = () => {
    let titleError = '';
    let descriptionError = '';
    const { title, description } = this.state;
    const trimTitle = title.trim();

    if (trimTitle === '') titleError = 'The title cannot be empty';
    if (title.length > 500)
      titleError = 'The title cannot be longer than 500 characters';
    if (description.length > 2000)
      descriptionError =
        'The description cannot be longer than 2000 characters';

    if (titleError !== '' || descriptionError !== '') {
      this.setState({ titleError, descriptionError });
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };
```

I've tried to make the functions like these:

```
emptyTitle = ({ titleError }) => {
    // let titleError = '';
    const trimTitle = title.trim();
    if (trimTitle === '') titleError = 'The title cannot be empty';
    this.setState({ titleError });
  };

  maxTitleLength = ({ title }) => {
    let titleError = '';
    if (title.length > 500)
      titleError = 'The title cannot be longer than 500 characters';
    this.setState({ titleError });
  };
```

But I'm not sure about my approach. Please, I will really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have been asked to avoid imperative control flows, [`R.cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) is the functional way of encapsulating `if/else` logic. Hope it helps.

```js
const createValidator = (name, { min, max }) => R.cond([
  [
    // normalize and compare min-length
    R.pipe(R.trim, R.length, R.gte(min)), 
    // eventually return error message
    R.always(`${name} cannot be empty`)
  ],
  
  [
    // normalize and compare max-length
    R.pipe(R.trim, R.length, R.lt(max)), 
    // eventually return error message
    R.always(`${name} too long`)
  ],
  
  // all good, no errors to display
  [R.T, R.always(null)]
]);


// The following can be ignored, 
// only needed as boilerplate to prove the example
const Test = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState('');
  const withValue = (cb) => R.pipe(R.pathOr('', ['target', 'value']), cb);
  
  const isTitleValid = createValidator('Title', { min: 0, max: 500 });
  const isDescriptionValid = createValidator('Description', { min: 0, max: 2000 });
  
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Title" value={title} onChange={withValue(setTitle)} />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Description"  onChange={withValue(setDescription)} value={description} />
      </div>
      
      <ul className="text-danger">
        <li>{isTitleValid(title)}</li>
        <li>{isDescriptionValid(description)}</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector('#test'));
```

```css
form { margin: 1em 2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id=test></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply all the validation rules and get all the errors, you can normalize the input to be able to accumulate the results:

```js
/* You can create all validation functions following the pattern:
 * validationFunc(rule, msg)(normalizedParam): ValidationResult
 */
 
 const normalizeParam = param => {
   if (typeof param.errors === 'undefined') {
     return {
       value: param,
       errors: []
     }
   }
   
   return param
 }
 
 const makeError = function (param, msg) {
   return {
     ...param,
     errors: param.errors.concat(msg)
   }
 }
 
 const makeRule = (msg, rule) => param => {
   const normalizedParam = normalizeParam(param)
   
   if (rule(normalizedParam.value)) {
      return normalizedParam
   } else {
      return makeError(normalizedParam, msg)
   }
 }
 
 const validationGreaterThan = (limit, msg) => makeRule(msg, function(param) {
    return param > limit
 })
 
 const validationLesserThan = (limit, msg) => makeRule(msg, function(param) {
    return param < limit
 })
 
 const validate = R.compose(
    validationGreaterThan(10, 'The number must be greater than 10'),
    validationLesserThan(100, 'The number must be lesser than 100')
 )
 
 let result = validate(1)

 if (result.errors.length) {
   result.errors.forEach(err => console.log(err))
 } else {
   console.log('Success!')
 }
 
 result = validate(101)
 
  if (result.errors.length) {
   result.errors.forEach(err => console.log(err))
 } else {
   console.log('Success!')
 }
 
  result = validate(20)
 
  if (result.errors.length) {
   result.errors.forEach(err => console.log(err))
  } else {
   console.log('Success!')
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

But if you want to cut the validation process, you can throw an exception when an error is found (each validation throws an error or returns the parameter if all went ok).

You can investigate other approaches here:

- See: https://codeburst.io/composable-object-validations-in-js-efa1ebacc34e
- See conceptos of predicates and rules: https://medium.com/javascript-inside/form-validation-as-a-higher-order-component-pt-1-83ac8fd6c1f0
- See Validation Functor: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-programming-in-js-with-practical-examples-part-2-429d2e8ccc9e/

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible implementation using [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) cond method:

```js
this.state = {title: '', description: ''};

this.setState = (s) => { console.log(s); };

isEmpty = (t) => (t === '');

isLong = (t, n) => (t.length > n);

emptyTitle = (t) => isEmpty(t.trim());

longTitle = (t) => isLong(t, 500);

longDesc = (d) => isLong(d, 2000);

titleValidator = R.cond([
  [emptyTitle, R.always('The title cannot be empty')],
  [longTitle, R.always('The title cannot be longer than 500 characters')],
  [R.T, R.always('')]
]);

descValidator = R.cond([
  [longDesc, R.always('The description cannot be longer than 2000 characters')],
  [R.T, R.always('')]
]);

thereIsError = (e) => (e.title !== '' || e.description !== '');

errorDetected = function (e) {
  this.setState(e); 
  return false;
};

validate = () => {
    const { title, description } = this.state;

    const validationError = {
      title: titleValidator(title), 
      description: descValidator(description)
    };
    
    const errorLog = R.cond([
      [thereIsError, errorDetected],
      [R.T, R.T]
    ]); 
    
    return errorLog(validationError);
};

console.log('Validate:', validate.call(this));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `compose` sounds wrong to me, every function gets called with the wrong value as soon as one of them returns an error message...

Comment: That's true, I haven't thought about that. I just saw your answer and the `createValidator` is an awesome solution. I'll try to make it better based on your code, thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer to avoid the wrong value issue. Now I'm using `R.cond` instead of compose, it's not really good to read but seems to be working fine.

Comment: sorry, but this answer is still far from helping the OP... why reassigning `setState`? `thereIsError` only checks for emptiness, a lot of custom declarations are built-in in ramda... not declaring vars might be misleading for a person who is learning and the usage of `this` looks strange...

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto and hitmands Thank you! I really appreciate your help! I'll study about what you are saying, I'm learning a lot!